# SQL Server 2008 R2 Trigger multiple rows in a single batch update issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-update

I have implemented a trigger in SQL Server 2008 R2 in this way -

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgtblOrgStaffAssocLastUpdate] ON [dbo].[tblOrgStaffAssoc]
       AFTER UPDATE
    AS

    IF EXISTS (SELECT i.* FROM INSERTED i inner join deleted d on i.ORG_ID = d.ORG_ID and isnull(i.StaffType, -1111) = isnull(d.StaffType, -1111)
    where i.Deleted = 0
    and (isnull(i.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) <> isnull(d.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier))          
    ))
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
        BEGIN   

            --UPDATE PER_ID      
            update l    
            set PER_ID = 1, UpdatedOn =  GETDATE()
            from dbo.tblOrgStaffAssocLastUpadate l inner join [dbo].[inserted] i on l.ORG_ID = i.ORG_ID and l.StaffType = i.StaffType
            inner join [dbo].[deleted] d on i.ORG_ID = d.ORG_ID and i.StaffType = d.StaffType
            where isnull(i.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) <> isnull(d.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier))          
        END         

END
```

My purpose is to update tblOrgStaffAssocLastUpadate  when tblOrgStaffAssoc is updated.  For only one row, it works fine.  However for multiple rows send over in one batch, it updates one row only in tblOrgStaffAssocLastUpadate while tblOrgStaffAssoc has multiple rows updated.

When I use a intermediate tables _Inserted and _deleted to buffer the INSERTED and DELETED data and use the permanent tables to update like this way -

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgtblOrgStaffAssocLastUpdate] ON [dbo].[tblOrgStaffAssoc]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT i.* FROM INSERTED i inner join deleted d on i.ORG_ID = d.ORG_ID and isnull(i.StaffType, -1111) = isnull(d.StaffType, -1111)
where i.Deleted = 0
and (isnull(i.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) <> isnull(d.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier))          
))
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN   
        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[_inserted]') AND type in (N'U'))
            insert into [dbo].[_inserted]
            select * from inserted 
        else
            select * into [dbo].[_inserted]
            from inserted

        IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[_deleted]') AND type in (N'U'))
            insert into [dbo].[_deleted]
            select * from deleted 
        else
            select * into [dbo].[_deleted]
            from deleted

        --UPDATE PER_ID      
        update l    
        set PER_ID = 1, UpdatedOn =  GETDATE()
        from dbo.tblOrgStaffAssocLastUpadate l inner join [dbo].[_inserted] i on l.ORG_ID = i.ORG_ID and l.StaffType = i.StaffType
        inner join [dbo].[_deleted] d on i.ORG_ID = d.ORG_ID and i.StaffType = d.StaffType
        where isnull(i.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) <> isnull(d.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier))          
    END

END
```

It works fine.  Changing permanent table _Inserted to use #inserted or table variable @inserted does not work either.

Apparently using permanent table is not a good idea.  I don't know how the trigger works in this way.  Can anyone help out?

Thanks

Edit to answer @usr's comment -

It does not work correctly if I use -

```
update l set PER_ID = 1, UpdatedOn = GETDATE() from dbo.tblOrgStaffAssocLastUpadate l inner join [dbo].[inserted] i on l.ORG_ID = i.ORG_ID and l.StaffType = i.StaffType inner join [dbo].[deleted] d on i.ORG_ID = d.ORG_ID and i.StaffType = d.StaffType where isnull(i.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) <> isnull(d.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier))
```

Only one row is updated. The rest rows are not updated at all.  Even though I can see multiple rows returned if I use

```
select l.* from dbo.tblOrgStaffAssocLastUpadate l inner join [dbo].[inserted] i on l.ORG_ID = i.ORG_ID and l.StaffType = i.StaffType inner join [dbo].[deleted] d on i.ORG_ID = d.ORG_ID and i.StaffType = d.StaffType where isnull(i.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) <> isnull(d.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier))
```

right before the update statement. That is where I am totally confused why the next update statement only updates one row only, and why only permanent table can persist all the rows update but not temporary table and table variables.

Updated question -

Since multiple update rows are send to the table in a single batch.  It seems that the trigger's INSERT and DELETE table only one and the last one update row only at the time when I reach " update l  " statement.  Before that it holds multiple update rows.  I can see that when I use permanent tables. I just don't understand SQL Server behave in this way.  Anyone saw the same thing?

Comment: Why do you need all that tables anyway? The query under `--UPDATE PER_ID` looks fine. Why can't you use that alone?

Comment: @usr Thanks for your quick response.  It does not work correctly if I use "             update l    
            set PER_ID = 1, UpdatedOn =  GETDATE()
            from dbo.tblOrgStaffAssocLastUpadate l inner join [dbo].[inserted] i on l.ORG_ID = i.ORG_ID and l.StaffType = i.StaffType
            inner join [dbo].[deleted] d on i.ORG_ID = d.ORG_ID and i.StaffType = d.StaffType
            where isnull(i.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) <> isnull(d.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier))          
".  Only one row is updated. The rest rows are not updated at all

Comment: @usr I can even see multiple rows returned if I insert " select l.* from dbo.tblOrgStaffAssocLastUpadate l inner join [dbo].[inserted] i on l.ORG_ID = i.ORG_ID and l.StaffType = i.StaffType inner join [dbo].[deleted] d on i.ORG_ID = d.ORG_ID and i.StaffType = d.StaffType where isnull(i.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) <> isnull(d.PER_ID, cast(cast(0 as binary) as uniqueidentifier)) " right before the update statement.  I am totally confused why the next update statement only updates one row only.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seriously over-complicating this. You do not need all those checks and links between `INSERTED` and `DELETED`.

This is a trigger on `UPDATE` only, therefore, there will always be a `DELETED` table that contains for each changed row what *was* in the table and there will always be an `INSERTED` that contains for each changed row what *will be* in the table. So for your purposes you only need to deal with one of these tables. Rows that are not changed are in neither table.

If this was a trigger on `INSERT` there would only be an `INSERTED` table. Similarly, a `DELETE` trigger only has a `DELETED` table.

Secondly, you seem to think that NULL=NULL is true - it isn't. The statement NULL=NULL returns NULL. So does NULL<>NULL, NULL>=NULL etc. etc. In a database NULL means *not a value* and something that does not have a value is incomparable. So your where statement is also superfluous.

So I think the code you want is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgtblOrgStaffAssocLastUpdate] ON [dbo].[tblOrgStaffAssoc]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
   UPDATE l    
   SET PER_ID = 1
      ,UpdatedOn =  GETDATE()
   FROM dbo.tblOrgStaffAssocLastUpadate l
        INNER JOIN
        inserted i ON l.ORG_ID = i.ORG_ID and l.StaffType = i.StaffType
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  You are right in my over-complicating this but the complex joining should produce correct result since INSERT and DELETE hold the same thing.  For the second problem, since I don't think NULL=NULL, I used isnull function to check and convert the null value to be able to compare. Have I missed anything?

Comment: Beats me. Does it work? If it does you have probably covered everything :-)